# How to shut off water to pool

Tags: plumbing, water, pool

I would like to shut off water to the pool so that I can drain it--I don't want to shut off water at the main line near the curb of the house. I don't see any indication of how I might do this based on the pool's plumbing (picture attached). There are two valves (encased in black near the bottom of the image), but I don't know what those do. Would anyone like to explain to me what those two valves are and how I might shut off water to the pool? Thank you![image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo9AE.jpg)

Comment: What does that mean? Shut off water to the pool? Pools Don't automatically fill themselves with water. You mean you're looking for a valve to drain the pool?

Comment: @Sickest actually many pool do have fill valves or [auto levelers](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004VU8U52/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_2gCTCb2NB4Y2D), basically a side well with a float valve.  In the case of the model I linked a fluid master toilet float valve is found inside.  Google pool filler or pool leveler for many similar products both in-deck solutions and hang on the pool edge.

Comment: @Andrew I don’t see what looks like water supply valves here.  The pool fill shutoff valve may be in your basement or where ever the water supply for the pool comes from.   Do you have an underground irrigation/sprinkler system?  If so water may come from that source and the pool shutoff valve might in an in-ground valve box.

Comment: @andrew also draining a pool is not like draining the bathtub.  Specifically the weight of the water in a pool plays an important part.  In a vinyl liner pools the water literally holds the liner in place, draining the water can have disastrous outcomes for someone unfamiliar.  Plaster pools there is a [different problem](https://images.app.goo.gl/wpCF98KtFd7js2CA8) where the entire pool can float out of the ground if the water table in your area is high.  Why do you want to drain the pool?